# How to distribute a Java program and make it install a one time software

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver, software-distribution

Sorry if the title is confusing; I am not sure how to word the question.

I am building a Java program that uses Selenium, Apache POI, and GeckoDriver to automate a task. I am wanting to make it an executable so it can run on other machines without IDEs. I understand how to make an executable JAR that can run on other computers, but these other computers will not have FireFox or GeckoDriver downloaded. Therefore, I am wondering how to make my program download the prerequisite software one time so it can work on other machines.

Even if my solution has to just end up getting the other computers to download the dependencies, I was generally wondering how one would go about packaging external libraries, software, etc with a program/what the terminology is.

Thank you in advance, and sorry if this is confusing. First time deploying an application and not familiar with all the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows based distribution you can make an installer with [InstallForge](https://installforge.net/).

Its freeware. You can configure where put your jar, and the shortcuts in Start Menu. And also attach your dependencies installer, and execute commands (e.g run silent install of Firefox) inside the setup.exe generated by installForce.